# Malloc assertion failed in C

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I am going through the cs50x course, doing speller check program. In my fourth implementation of this program I've ran into malloc problem.
This time I decided to implement a binary tree.
I've read a lot of threads about this problem and checked my code for several times, but I still can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Problem appears in the recursive function that loads dictionary into ram.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"



// standart node of the trie
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node* less;
    struct node* more;
}
node;

// Function definitions
void unload_node(node* pr_node);
void ld_bin_tree(int min, int max, node* node);
bool check_word(char* lword, node* parent);

// Global variables
// root of the tree
node* root;
FILE* dict;
//size of dictionary
int dict_size = 0;

bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    // open dictionary file 
    dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    int nwords = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    root = malloc(sizeof(node));

    //if file wasn't open
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening ditionary file!");
        return false;
    }

    // tmp storage for read word
    char buffer[LENGTH + 1];

    // count words in the dictionary
    while(fscanf(dict, "%s", buffer) > 0)
    {
        nwords++;
    }
    max = nwords;
    rewind(dict);
    ld_bin_tree(min, max, root);


    // close file
    fclose(dict);
    return false;
}
/*
 * Recursion function to fill in binary tree
 */

void ld_bin_tree(int min, int max, node* node)
{
    // tmp word holder
    char buffer[LENGTH + 1];

    // next mid value
    int mid = (min + max) / 2;

    // if mid == 0 then the bottom of the brunch reached, so return
    if(max - min < 2)
    {
        if(min == 0)
        {
            fscanf(dict, "%s", node->word);
            dict_size++;
            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    // go through the dict to the mid string
    for(int i = 0; i <= mid; i++)
    {
        fscanf(dict, "%s", buffer);
    }

    // fill in word 
    strcpy(node->word, buffer);
    // go at the beginning of the dict
    rewind(dict);

    // fill in input node
    // fill in new children nodes
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

    node->less = new_node;

    // send lesser side
    ld_bin_tree(min, mid, node->less);

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node->more = new_node;
    // send greater side
    ld_bin_tree(mid, max, node->more);

    dict_size++;
    return;
}
```

I've tried to get this error using valgrind but it gives me a lot of warnings about reading and writing in unappropriated memory blocks. But because I'm not very good with programming yet, this warnings didn't give me a clue of what's happening.

So I'm asking for more precise help, if it's possible. Thank you in advance.

Other parts of the speller program may be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m1q1ui2g490fls7/AACnVhjjdFpv1J0mUUhY2uV2a?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function `ld_bin_tree()` you have

```
struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Here `node` is a pointer not an object of type `struct node`.

You have

`node *node;`

So the global definition of `node` is being overwritten which makes it a pointer.

So you are not allocating memory for your whole structure. You should have

```
struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: Ah, yes. `node* node` is a nasty declaration, as it redefines the meaning of `node`.

Comment: Or just write `malloc(sizeof(*new_node));` which would either fix or expose such bugs.